# Custom Fields, linking to a separate download page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Afternoon all,

I have some Advanced Custom Fields set up, which allow the user to download files which are appropriate to a certain product.

For example, if the product was 'Product 1', the files would be 'Product 1 size' etc. This works perfectly, using the following:

```
 <a href="<?php the_field('brochure'); ?>">Brochure</a>
```

This adds the file which is added on each individual page, as in ACF I have set the location rules as shown in the screenshot

[image: location of custom field]

Now, the issue is as follows.

I need to create a whole new page, called downloads.

This page, will list all the products in my page, and then need to have the downloads available (the Custom Field File). Now, because this field is set up to show on the product pages, I am completely unsure as to how to show the downloads on a seperate page, because using

```
    <a href="<?php the_field('brochure'); ?>">Brochure</a>
```

is technically not telling me which product this is for.

I hope this makes sense.

EDIT:

I completely forgot to mention, this information will need to be inside a table, and I am currently using TablePress, a plugin.

So it would go like:

Prouduct   ---   Category --- Download

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have edited your question, my first answer does not make sense anymore. So here is what I suggest now:

**A. This is the solution to what you actually asked**

1. Install the [Reveal IDs Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/reveal-ids-for-wp-admin-25/) so you can see in the admin panel what post-IDs your products have
2. Look up the ID for a specific product
3. In your TablePress table-cell you paste the ACF-shortcode:

   `<a href="[acf field="brochure" post_id="12"]">Download brochure</a>`

`post_id="12"`: this is the ID of your product-post which you can look up with Reveal IDs.

I already tested this right now, so I do know it's working.

**B. Another solution that is more a question**

Your ACF field '*brochure'* obviously contains a URL to a file which might be available in your WP media library too?!

When this is the case you don't need the ACF field for your table. You can just:

1. click "Advanced Editor" (when working with the table)click into a table cell
2. click into a table cell
3. click "Add files" and link to your file directly this way

Maybe that is an option too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. This should point you in the right direction: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/